# Typescript easy way to get property from inners objects

Tags: typescript

i have this object structure:

```
let data = {
   prop1 = {
        prop11 = {
          prop111 = 'hello'
        },
        prop12 = {...}
   },
   prop2= {...}
}
```

And i have this formated string: `'data.prop1.prop11.prop111'`

I would like to map this string to data structure and get value (in this example 'hello'). Its general data structure, I dont know how names of property is in (not solid property names).
It is easy way how to do it? Probably I need parse string to array and then?

Thank you for advices

Comment: Do you want to do a kind of property file?

Comment: Exactly. But i need to properties are in "namespaces" (parent properties). And I need to get value using string path in this structure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: You should rearrange your solution like let properties =
 {"prop1.prop11.prop111" = "hello ", "prop1.prop12" = {...}};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a similar function few months ago,

Let's say you have this object:

```
var obj = {
    data: {
        prop1: {
            prop11: {
                prop111: 'hello'
            },
            prop12: "12"
        },
        prop2: "1"
    }
}
```

Then, you can use this function (JavaScript):

```
function getDescendantProp(obj, desc) {
    var arr = desc.split(".");
    if (arr.length > 0 && arr[0] !== "") {
        while (arr.length) {
            var name = arr.shift();
            if (name in obj) {
                obj = obj[name];
            } else {
                console.warn('[getDescendantProp] - ' + name + ' property does not exists.');
                return undefined;
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

TypeScript Code:

```
function getDescendantProp(obj: {[key: string]: {}}, desc: string) {
    if (obj === null || obj === undefined || desc === "") {
        return undefined;
    }
    const arr: string[] = desc.split(".");
    if (arr.length > 0 && arr[0] !== "") {
        while (arr.length) {
            const name: string | undefined = arr.shift();
            if ((typeof name === "string") && (name in obj)) {
                obj = obj[name];
            } else {
                console.warn("[getDescendantProp] - " + name + " property does not exists.");
                return undefined;
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

And use it:

```
getDescendantProp(obj, "data.prop1.prop11.prop111") // hello
```

Comment: Thats great! Thanks

Comment: no problem. I just edited my post adding the same function but using TypeScript 2.4